# Sum - arithmetic series x 2

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

I know the formula for arithmetic series. What if the difference in the arithmtic series is changing by 1 unit each term.

Can you help me find the general term and sum for:

0+3+7+12+18+25....

Comment: Try looking at the differences of elements $3-0,7-3,12-7,18-12$ can you guess the formula for the sequence of differences?

Comment: The difference of the first twp terms is 3. Next terms terms is 4. Next two terms is 5

Comment: Try summing few terms of the differences of elements what do you get?
i.e for $2$ terms you get $3+4$

Comment: [This website](http://oeis.org/search?q=0%2C+3%2C+7%2C+12%2C+18%2C+25&sort=&language=&go=Search) might be useful for the future.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88277/how-to-find-nth-term-of-the-sequence-3-7-12-18-25-ldots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
T_2-T_1=3
\\
T_3-T_2=4
\\
...
\\
T_n-T_{n-1}=n+1
$$
Summing them together :
$$
T_n-T_1=(n+1)(n+2)-3
\\
T_n=\frac{n^2+3n-4}{2}
\\
\sum_{p=1}^n T_i=\sum_{p=1}^n \frac{p^2+3p-4}{2}
$$
I'll leave the rest to you.

Comment: @Surb yes. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Just as a reminder. This question does not have a unique answer there are infinitely many polynomials satisfying this series.

One easy polynomial is $$a_n=n(n+5)/2=0.5n^2+2.5n$$

Comment: How did you derive that formula?

Comment: Just used $n(n+a)/2$ as a test because there seemed to be a quadratic term involved and determined $a$.