# Proof by induction of a Fibonacci relation

Tags: induction, fibonacci-numbers

We know:

$F_0 = 0$

$F_1 = 1$

$F_i = F_{i-1} + F_{i-2}$ for $i \geq 2$

Prove by induction:

$F_i = \dfrac{\phi^i-{\phi^{*}}^i}{\sqrt{5}}$

where $\phi = (1+\sqrt{5}) / 2$ and $\phi = (1-\sqrt{5}) / 2$.

My attempt:

Base case: $i = 0$: $F_0 = 0$ (easy to show)

Assume true for $i = k$ and $i = k + 1$.

We have:

$F_k = \dfrac{\phi^k-{\phi^{*}}^k}{\sqrt{5}}$

and

$F_{k+1} = \dfrac{\phi^{k+1}-{\phi^{*}}^{k+1}}{\sqrt{5}}$

Show it holds for $i = k + 2$ to complete induction. This is where I'm stuck. I have tried:

$F_{k+2} = F_{k+1} + F_{k} = \dfrac{\phi^{k+1}-{\phi^{*}}^{k+1}}{\sqrt{5}} + \dfrac{\phi^k-{\phi^{*}}^k}{\sqrt{5}}$

$F_{k+2} = \dfrac{\phi^k(1+\phi)-{\phi^{*}}^{k}(1+{\phi^*})}{\sqrt{5}}$

but I'm not sure where to go from here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have a mistake in the last line, $\phi^{k+1} + \phi^k = \phi^k(1+\phi)$ and ditto for $\phi^\ast$. Now use $\phi^2 = 1+\phi$ (and ditto ...)

Comment: Thanks Daniel - I wasn't aware of that property. Are there any other ways of proving this without use of that property?

Comment: @AliAmiri, that one was (rightly) closed for not showing any work/interest by who asked. This is different.

Comment: You need *two* base cases, $i = 0$ and $i = 1$ to get started. The property alluded to by  @DanielFisher is since $\phi^2 - \phi - 1 = 0$ (solve the quadratic, the roots are your $\phi$ and $\phi^*$).

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\rm\quad \phi^{\:n+1}\!-\:\bar\phi^{\:n+1} =\ (\phi+\bar\phi)\ (\phi^n\!-\:\bar\phi^n)\ -\ \phi\:\bar\phi\ (\phi^{\:n-1}\!-\:\bar\phi^{\:n-1})$

Hence, upon substituting $\rm\,\ \phi+\bar\phi\ =\ 1\ =\ -\phi\bar\phi\ $ and dividing by $\:\phi-\bar\phi = \sqrt 5\:$ we deduce $\rm\ \ldots$

**Remark** $\ $ To understand the essence of the matter it's worth emphasizing that such an inductive proof amounts *precisely* to  showing that $\rm\:f_n\:$ and  $\rm\: \bar{f}_n = (\phi^n-\bar\phi^n)/(\phi-\bar\phi)\:$ are both solutions of the difference equation (recurrence) $\rm\ f_{n+2} = f_{n+1} + f_n\:,\:$ with initial conditions $\rm\ f_0 = 0,\ f_1 = 1\:.\:$ The (trivial) induction simply proves the *uniqueness* of such solutions. It will prove quite instructive to structure the proof from this standpoint. It will also mean that you can later *reuse* this uniqueness theorem for recurrences.

Generally, just as above, uniqueness theorems provide very powerful tools for proving equalities - a point which I emphasize in [many prior posts.](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:math.stackexchange.com+dubuque+uniqueness+theorem+proving) For example, see my prior posts on [telescopy](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+telescopy) and the [fundamental theorem of difference calculus,](http://www.google.com/search?q=site:math.stackexchange.com+dubuque+fundamental+theorem+%22difference+calculus%22) esp. [this one.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/72668/242)

Answer (score 1):

Use $1+\phi=\phi^2$, to get 
$$
F_{k+2} = \dfrac{\phi^k(1+\phi)-{\phi^{*}}^{k}(1+{\phi^{*}})}{\sqrt{5}}= \dfrac{\phi^{k+2}-{\phi^{*}}^{(k+2)}}{\sqrt{5}}
$$